# Synchronize Tables with HTTP and eventually progress bar update

Tags: c#, .net

I've a WPF application that after the login needs to get some data from some tables. There're some tables for example countries that needs to be loaded only once, and other that're plannings that need to be updated at each login/syncronization.

Since it will work via HTTP I was wondering what's the best approach to ask for the data and get them back.

I was thinking of sending the Table I need to an HTTP WebApi endpoint, then giving the data via json/jsonp. Is this fine? Is there a way I can update the client via HTTP? in order to provide the WPF GUI a progress of the sync operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some architectural advice you should always bring some more detailed information about the environment which you are going to set up.

For example:

Where is the data located at the moment?

- a) The data is stored within a database entity
- b) The data is stored within local json files (or similar)
- c) The data is stored within external json files (or similar)
- ...

How is the data provided to clients?

- a) The data is provided by an already existing REST API
- b) The data will be provided by a REST API which needs to be developed
- ...

And so on. It would make it easier to understand what you are planning to do.

But anyway I understand it like this:

You are planning to develop a WPF client application to visualize data. The data to be visualize needs to be refreshed on each login within the client application. The data is currently placed within accessable database entities.

To reach the goal I'd create a REST API using .Net Core. If your database entities are existing within a Microsoft SQL or Orcale SQL server you are able to use EntityFramework for .net Core with the corresponding managed database providers by installing them within your .net Core Project via NuGet.

With entity framework installed, you are able to easily access your data as actual .net objects. Those objects can easily be serialized to json and delivered by the .Net Core Framework. You provide the json by implementing a so called controller within your backend service.

Within your client application, implement a HttpClient to consume your newly created .Net Core Backend API. You can easily implement some kind of progress bar to wait for your requests to finish.

That said, here are some links for you to look up and research the technologies I described before:

.Net-Core BackEnd Example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

EntityFramework Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/

WPF client consuming REST API example:

https://somedeveloperblog.com/2018/05/22/cosuming-rest-api-in-a-wpf-application/

I hope that helps a little. For more detailed answers, please provide a more specific question.

Regards

Comment: thanks for your reply,that's the exact scenario but I've got some point to spot.. that was exacly what I would have implemented myself but I'm not aware of how to show the progress bar that's real and not in an indeterminate state. Another thing it would be best to perform a query (if possible) that returns a dynamic object

Comment: I'm not really getting your point. In which scenario would a progress bar be in a indeterminate state? .Net provides an actual control for use in wpf applications: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.progressbar?view=netframework-4.8. The request itself should always return the data at is current state, so it is always refreshed when a new login is performed.